# Stripping a decimal and remaining zeros off an alphanumeric string

Tags: php, trim

I'm returning orders on my success page in magento. The problem is on my quantity (QTY) variable it returns like QTY 2.0000

I've tried several things like `$itemQTY_str + 0` which i think is only good for non alphanumeric strings. Additionally, I've tried `(floatval)$itemQTY_str`

```
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('increment_id',$this->getOrderId());
$order=$order->getFirstItem();

$order_items=$order->getAllVisibleItems();

$productIds=array();
$itemSKU_str = $itemAMT_str = $itemQTY_str = '';
$i = 1;

foreach($order_items as $order_item) {  
    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($order_item->getProductId());

    if($_product->getData('fb_pinterest_share')) {
        $productIds[]=$order_item->getProductId();
    }

    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '00.00.00.000'){      
        $itemSKU_str = $itemSKU_str . 'ITEM'. $i . '=' . $order_item->getSku() . '&';
        $itemAMT_str = $itemAMT_str . 'AMT'. $i . '=' . $order_item->getPrice() . '&';
        $itemQTY_str = $itemQTY_str . 'QTY'. $i . '=' . $order_item->getQtyOrdered() . '&';
    }

    $i++;

}

/* COMMISSION JUNCTION TRACKING CODE - START */
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '00.00.00.000'){
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', '******', '*******', '*******');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        //echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{  
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "
            SELECT  customer_id
            FROM    sales_flat_order
            WHERE   status = 'complete'
            AND     customer_email LIKE '" . $order->getCustomerEmail() . "'
        ");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            //returning customer
            echo '
<iframe height="1" width="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.emjcd.com/tags/c?containerTagId=4813&amp;' . $itemSKU_str . $itemAMT_str . (float)$itemQTY_str . 'CID=1527930&amp;OID=' . $this->getOrderId() . '&amp;TYPE=362236&amp;CURRENCY=USD" name="cj_conversion"></iframe>
            ';
        }else{
            //new customer
            echo '
<iframe height="1" width="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.emjcd.com/tags/c?containerTagId=4812&amp;' . $itemSKU_str . $itemAMT_str . $itemQTY_str . 'CID=1527930&amp;OID=' . $this->getOrderId() . '&amp;TYPE=362235&amp;CURRENCY=USD" name="cj_conversion"></iframe>
            ';
        }
    }
}
```

it returns:

```
<iframe height="1" width="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.emjcd.com/tags/c?containerTagId=4813&amp;ITEM1=59444-no-subscription&amp;ITEM2=793573106964-one-time&amp;AMT1=37.0000&amp;AMT2=65.0000&amp;QTY1=2.0000&amp;QTY2=3.0000&amp;CID=1527930&amp;OID=100000928&amp;TYPE=362236&amp;CURRENCY=USD" name="cj_conversion"></iframe>


QTY1=2.0000&amp;QTY2=3.0000
```

**Ultimate goal:**

```
QTY1=2&amp;QTY2=3.
```

I've also tried editing the string directly..

```
$itemQTY_str = $itemQTY_str . 'QTY'. $i . + 0 '=' . $order_item->getQtyOrdered() . '&';

$itemQTY_str = $itemQTY_str . 'QTY'. $i . '=' . $order_item->getQtyOrdered(). + 0 . '&';
```

Hopefully that's clear.. help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what do you want to get in the end? `QTY 2` or just `2`?

Comment: What i would like in the end is just QTY1=2&amp;QTY2=3.... with nothing else after the qty amount.. no decimal and no zeros.

Comment: Try `sprintf('%d', value, result)`

Comment: @Cheery QTY2 with no trailing decimal or zeros

Comment: for clarification: the given result by your query is i.e. 'QTY 2.000' and you want that changed to 2 ? Or did I get this wrong?

Comment: That's coorect @boulder_02. YES.

Comment: try regular expression. is the strind always beginning with 'QTY ' ?

Comment: It always begins with QTY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the value as an integer.

```
$itemQTY_str = $itemQTY_str . 'QTY'. $i . '=' . (int)$order_item->getQtyOrdered() . '&';
```

Comment: That seemed to make the QTY disappear altogether.

Comment: Yes, if the string starts with 'QTY', the (int) function will return 0

Comment: Ahh that's the entire string. Ok, so you need to cast the quantity value as an int as you build the $itemQTY_str. I've edited my code.